# Iframe scrollHeight return iframe height and not document height

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I'm trying to get the height of a page inside an iFrame using scrollHeight, but it only returns the height of the iframe and not of the page inside it.

I'm using vuejs and I tried scrollheight, offsetheight and also style.height but they don't work, I also tried to change how I reference the document to but it still doesn't work.
Hopefully someone could point me into the right direction. Any help or feedback is appreciated :)

**This is my vue component:**

```
<template>
    <q-card class="embed-card">
        <iframe :src="embed" frameborder="0" ref="lookerIframe"></iframe>
    </q-card>
</template>

<script>
    import { defineComponent } from "vue";

    export default defineComponent({
        name: "embed-card",
        props: {
            embed: {
                required: true,
            },
        },
        data: () => ({
            iFrameHeight: "",
        }),
        mounted() {
            this.iFrameHeight = this.$refs.lookerIframe.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + "px";
            console.log(this.iFrameHeight);
        },
    });
</script>
```

Thank you everyone for any help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think your iframe element has padding or something you can delete padding or margin of your iframe using this :

```
<iframe :src="embed" frameborder="0" ref="lookerIframe" style="margin:0;padding:0;"></iframe>
```

I hope it had been useful for you.

Comment: please use it with iframe.style.height

Comment: and scrollheight is the value which the user scrolled that element